# dropdown-toggle .click() not work

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Basically I want a click on one `<A>` to trigger a click event on the other `<A>` to show the dropdown menu. Here is the code: [the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mfUxU/)

```
//not working
$('#foo').click(function(){$('#bar').click();});

//but this works
//$('#foo').click(function(){$('#bar').click();alert();});
```

Could someone please tell me what's going on? Thanks!

Comment: Alternatively, you could consider including the caret after the User label directly, so you don't need any additional JS at all: `<a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><i class="icon-user icon-white"></i> User&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span></a>` http://jsfiddle.net/mfUxU/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `return false`, it should work

```
$('#foo').click(function(){$('#bar').click();return false;});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mfUxU/2/